# Multi domain or substore cart sharing

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, multistore, php-7, multidomain

Is it possible to share a customer's cart with different domains or substores?

If yes:

- tell me what to use either domain or substore.
- how to set this up

We have multiple domain names e.g. website1, website2, website3 and so on.

Scenario: if the customer adds a product to the cart from **website1** and I also add a product from **website2** both products should be displayed in the cart. If the customer decides to checkout on website2 the order should contain both products (from website1 and website2) but with the order id of website2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible when you make a change to: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php`. Please refer to this article for more information: https://astrio.net/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores/

Comment: Hi Mizuti, thanks for your answer. We don't want to use this option anymore in magento 1 because we want to switch to magento 2 in the near future. So i'll try to fix this in the new magento version. I do think this is the correct answer.